# convert json to xml using a plugin in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xml

I found a plugin to convert JSON to XML however its not working on IE, just wondering if anyone had this issue on IE.

I'm using this https://github.com/abdmob/x2js.

I'm trying to convert my JSON to XML on success of AJAX call, however on IE it's giving me an error `X2JS is undefined` but the jsfiddle example on the github seems to be working fine as well as on other browser like Chrome.

```
$.get(apiUrlPath)
    .then(function (data) {
        var x2js = new X2JS();
        var json2XMLResult = x2js.json2xml_str(data);
        console.log(data, json2XMLResult)
    })
```

Does anyone know why its not working on IE?

Comment: I downloaded the branch from github, ran the samples.html file locally with IE, and created a new X2JS() object in the console and it works just fine. Make sure you have loaded the xml2json.js script on your site. Also check for IE security restrictions if you are sure the script is loaded correctly.

Comment: The project looks like it hasn't been updated in a while. There are a few pull requests regarding the IE issue. I would look for a new solution if I was you, either that or write your own.

Comment: which version `IE` do you use?

Comment: Have you tried [fast xml parser](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser)? I believe it works in IE7+